# Tomcat Sessions storage directory

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi I have created a simple web application which involves session management and hosted it in Tomcat. I am able to view the current active sessions using the tomcat manager. Can you let me know in which directory are the sessions data stored in raw format. I have been searching a lot for the answer but couldn't find it yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check `work/SESSIONS.ser` file as indicated in the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Standard_Implementation) ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell I did check in the work directory but could never find any .ser file. Is there anyway to enable it or any property to be set?